# autocomplete javascript not working in master page with asp control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This script is working in individual web form.But same script is not working in page using master page.

I tried this in separate file ....If i call this same script ,not working.

Added webmethod

```
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtAutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Haha.aspx/GetCategory",
                data: "{'term':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete").val() + "','term1':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete1").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#txtAutoComplete1").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Haha.aspx/GetCategory1",
                data: "{'term':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete").val() + "','term1':'" + $("#txtAutoComplete1").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});    </script>
```

[WebMethod]

```
    public static List<string> GetCategory(string term, string term1)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(term1))
            term1 = " ";
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        Business.ClientBusinessLayerSQL ObjMgnr = new Business.ClientBusinessLayerSQL();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = ObjMgnr.fnLocationSearch(term, term1, "GET-SEARCH-1");
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //result.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LocName"].ToString());
            result.Add(row["LocName"].ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCategory1(string term, string term1)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        Business.ClientBusinessLayerSQL ObjMgnr = new Business.ClientBusinessLayerSQL();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = ObjMgnr.fnLocationSearch(term, term1, "GET-SEARCH-2");
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            result.Add(row["LocName"].ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what does `console says`??

Comment: Use ClientIDMode="Static". Master page change the ID of the control.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: It is not showing any error. During debugging,debug point is not going to cs file

Comment: You have written two methods which one is not working ?

Comment: I am using two textbox for predictive search.Both methods not working.

Comment: Whenever a control is inside a Master Page, the client ID of the control would get appended with its content placeholder ID. So, for an element with an ID “txtAutoComplete”, the new client ID would look something like “ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ txtAutoComplete”. So, when you try to use $(‘#txtAutoComplete’), you will not get access to the txtAutoComplete textbox in JavaScript. You need to access it by calling $(‘#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ txtAutoComplete’).

Comment: Show your WebMethod code.

Comment: Check your browser console you will se error details there.

Comment: Have you checked the console ?

Comment: This is my console error                                                                          Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3:0
TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function car_booking.aspx:102:0

Comment: Update the question with files referred from your project.

Comment: You may not be referring the files correctly.

Comment: if i am not refering the files correctly,then how it worked for individual web form

Comment: Path may have changed fro this.

Comment: Inside the script,i set two alert msg but first alert only working.. That's means ".autocomplete" is not executing.   $(document).ready(function() {                                         alert("hi");
    $("#txtAutoComplete").autocomplete({                      alert("hiii");

Comment: Yes that is what i am saying that it is not finding the autocomplete js if you check your console you will see 404 error there.

Comment: Okay...when i checked console,it showed '304 not modifided' on status

Comment: You need to refresh your cache press ctrl + F5 or clear cache of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have same ID of textboxes as controls placed inside master page inherit the contentplaceholder id.So for this use `ClientIDMode="Static"`. Also when you pass data in ajax call both paramter name and its value should be `in quotes` or you should use `JSON.stringify` and `name of parameters` in ajax call and in WebMethod `should be same`. And your `WebMethods` should be `static`.

Your autocomplete js is not loading. You are referring it directly from internet. Download the file and place inside your project and refer it from there.

Comment: No.I tried But i am getting same error

Comment: Thanks @MairajAhamad . I got script conflict.That's why i had problem in autocomplete. Now i removed conflicted jquery and autocomplete is working.